# Is there a way to have more than one input in a function after its written?

Tags: javascript, function

I pretty new at this and have been trying to learn more about using Arrays in Javascript. 
I have been making some functions where I would take the array, and the new input and stick it into a fucntion that is like:

```js
function printArray(array){
    //This function will print out each of the entries of the array 
    console.log("This is the Output from the Print Array Function: ")
    console.time()
    let arr = array;
    for(let index = 0; index < arr.length; index++){
        console.log(arr[index]);
        //This is the function
    }
    console.timeEnd();
}
```

This is fine for just using a single argument in the function: but when I tried to do something similar with the `array.push()` the original syntax is: `array.prototype.push(input1 --> InputN)` I suppose that is is my question, how can I replicate inside the function arguements that it can be either a single input or a number of inputs. This is what I done instead:

```js
function singlePushArray(array,input){
    //This function ADDS ONE ITEM to the END OF THE ARRAY
    console.time();
    console.log("This is the Output from the Single Push Array Function- Adding a Single Items to the END of the ARRAY")
    console.log("This is the Original Copy of the Array: ", array);
    array.push(input);//This is the function
    console.log("This is the Ammended Cop of the Array: ", array);
    console.timeEnd();
    
}

function doublePushArray(array,input1,input2){
    //This function ADDS TWO Items to the END OF THE ARRAY

    console.time();
    console.log("This is the Output from the Double Push Array Function - Adding TWO Items to the END OF THE ARRAY");
    console.log("This is the Original Copy of the Array: ", array);
    array.push(input1,input2);//This is the function
    console.log("This is the ammended Copy of the Array: ", array);
    console.timeEnd()
}
```

(please forgive the overkill of the console.logs and the timestamps. I'm just using it as learning aides.  If anyone can help me out it would greatly appreciated. 
Many Thanks =)

Comment: As far as I know, `Array.prototype.push()` does not accept arbitrary number of arguments. But you could use a rest parameter to collect your inputN in an Array and iterate over them (e.g. using `forEach()`) and push them individually.

A faster way could be to `concat()` the `array` with the `input`s and reassign the variable. This would create a new Array, so mutations in other places won't be considered (which is a good thing, I think).

Comment: @Ryuno-Ki of course it does. See the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#Syntax

Comment: I was trying to replicate the syntax ```arr.push(element1[, ...[, elementN]])``` without fully understanding what it was referring too. Im not fully certain as to the solutions that @Ryuno-Ki was suggesting, may an example could help elaborate some of the methods that you were referring to, if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) with `...`:

```js
function nPushArray(array, ...inputs) {
  //This function ADDS N ITEMS to the END OF THE ARRAY
  console.time();
  console.log("This is the Output from the n Push Array Function- Adding N Items to the END of the ARRAY")
  console.log("This is the Original Copy of the Array: ", array);
  array.push(...inputs); //This is the function
  console.log("This is the Ammended Cop of the Array: ", array);
  console.timeEnd();
}

//usage
nPushArray([1, 2, 3], 4, 5);
nPushArray([1, 2, 3], 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
```

Comment: using the spread operator there, I didnt even know that was possible. I have seen it about in a few other places and wondered. Thank you man, you are owed a pint.